# What does GCC __attribute__((mode(XX)) actually do?

Tags: c, attributes, c99, bignum

This arose from a question earlier today on the subject of bignum libraries and gcc specific hacks to the C language. Specifically, these two declarations were used:

```
typedef unsigned int dword_t __attribute__((mode(DI)));
```

On 32 bit systems and

```
typedef unsigned int dword_t __attribute__((mode(TI)));
```

On 64-bit systems.

I assume given this is an extension to the C language that there exists no way to achieve whatever it achieves in current (C99) standards.

So my questions are simple: is that assumption correct? And what do these statements do to the underlying memory? I think the result is I have `2*sizeof(uint32_t)` for a `dword` in 32-bit systems and `2*sizeof(uint64_t)` for 64-bit systems, am I correct?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

These allow you to explicitly specify a size for a type without depending on compiler or machine semantics, such as the size of 'long' or 'int'.

They are described fairly well [on this page](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gcc_80.html).

I quote from that page:

> QI: An integer that is as wide as the
> smallest addressable unit, usually 8
> bits.
>
> HI: An integer, twice as wide as
> a QI mode integer, usually 16 bits.
>
> SI: An integer, four times as wide as a QI
> mode integer, usually 32 bits.
>
> DI: An
> integer, eight times as wide as a QI
> mode integer, usually 64 bits.
>
> SF: A
> floating point value, as wide as a SI
> mode integer, usually 32 bits.
>
> DF: A
> floating point value, as wide as a DI
> mode integer, usually 64 bits.

So `DI` is essentially `sizeof(char) * 8`.

Further explanation, including `TI` mode, can be found [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gccint_53.html) (possibly better than the first link, but both provided for reference).

So `TI` is essentially `sizeof(char) * 16` (128 bits).

---

The old links are now dead, so here's [the official GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Modes.html#Machine-Modes).

Comment: Just what I needed, +1. Is there no "standard" way to get around this then, I take it? i.e. declare say a 128-bit type? In its current usage, we can `dword = word << 1` safely and easily; I'd rather not replace that with a function etc if I can help it.

Comment: @Ninefingers: In GCC you can use `__int128` I believe: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fint128.html.

Comment: @Ninefingers: GCC supports the extension types `__int128_t` and `__uint128_t` (at least on 64-bit platforms, not sure about 32-bit targets)

Comment: what about `__attribute__((mode(SD)))` ?

Comment: @haelix same as SF but for doubles?

Answer (score 3):

@haelix Just read this question and I also tried to understand this thing. By my reading: you can find the definitions in the [gcc/gcc/machmode.def] in GCC source tree. For 'SD' it should be:

```
    /* Decimal floating point modes.  */ 
DECIMAL_FLOAT_MODE (SD, 4, decimal_single_format);
```

and 'DECIMAL_FLOAT_MODE' says:

```
     DECIMAL_FLOAT_MODE (MODE, BYTESIZE, FORMAT);
declares MODE to be of class DECIMAL_FLOAT and BYTESIZE bytes
wide.  All of the bits of its representation are significant.
```