# 128 bit integer with c on windows?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, integer, 128-bit

Is there any c compiler on windows able to use 128 bit integers natively?
On example, you can use gcc on linux, with __uint128_t... any other chance on windows?
(It would be great if 128 bit worked on 32 bit computers as well! :D)

Matteo

Comment: I tried, but... looks like it doesn't recognize __uint128_t as a native type...

Comment: I can't get __int128 to work in MSVC for either x86 or x64: error [C4235](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e5yy2kb.aspx) not recognised on this architecture.

Comment: why are you wanting to do this? it won't be as optimal as natural integer sizes. Sounds like you want a basic bignum library.

Comment: @slartibartfast MinGW is a 32-bit compiler, which means there's no `__uint128_t` for you. You must use [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: `__int128` is supported on 64-bit architectures only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329541/does-gcc-support-128-bit-int-on-amd64

Comment: [Here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Support-for-128-bit-integer-type/879048) is the quite lively feature request at visualstudio.com.

Answer (score 2):

In GCC you can try `__attribute__((mode(...)))`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559025/what-does-gcc-attribute-modexx-actually-do) and [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/gccint_53.html), e.g.

```
typedef unsigned int myU128 __attribute__((mode(TI)));
```

The results depend on your platform, though.

Comment: That looked very good but.... "Unable to emulate TI" what does that mean? I've a i7 processor, 64 bit windows 7... what does this mean? Under linux 128 bit __uint128_t work perfectly, so... what does this mean?

Comment: @Matteo: Is your operating system 64bit, too? I'm not sure, the availability of the TI mode depends on the platform and it might just be that you don't have it...

Answer (score -1):

You could try using SSE intrinsics built into Visual C++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eawz414%28v=VS.80%29.aspx  (Look at the __m128 type).

Comment: SSE does not provide 128 bit integers, it provides only vectors of smaller integers (8-64 bit) which have a size of 128 bit as a whole.

Comment: SSE is not for 128-bit operations and you can't do normal 128-bit math efficiently with it. [practical BigNum AVX/SSE possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27923192/995714), [Is it possible to use SSE and SSE2 to make a 128-bit wide integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12200698/995714)